# DBIx Class Row virtual/non-persistent columns

Tags: perl, dbix-class, rose-db-object

Is it possible to add columns to a DBIx::Class::Row object that are virtual in that they are not saved to the database?  I am looking for functionality like Rose::DB::Object provides through its non-persistent columns  http://search.cpan.org/dist/Rose-DB-Object/lib/Rose/DB/Object/Metadata.pm#nonpersistent_columns

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding methods to the Result classes in your Schema?  That might get you to the same place.  The methods you add can't be used in ->search and won't be returned in ->get_columns, but depending on your use case, it may be enough.

Answer (score 2):

I just had to look this up again as I had a need for it.  You've probably got a solution already, but for others that come here looking: https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::Manual::FAQ#Misc

Basically either use Moose and create an attribute, or add something like this to your schema:

```
__PACKAGE__->mk_group_accessors('simple' => qw/non_column_data/); # must use simple group
```